# How to display p:fileUpload invalidFileMessage in p:growl

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, message, growl

I'm using `<p:fileUpload>` which is restricted to PDF only. However, the `invalidFileMessage` shows inside the `<p:fileUpload>` component. How can I show it in `<p:growl>` instead?

```
<p:fileUpload allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/"
              invalidFileMessage="File is Invalid. Only PDF files are allowed" />
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 11):

You can't handle this server side. The file type is validated at client side without hitting any code in server side. So, any suggestions which suggest to manually create `FacesMessage` and/or explicitly add `<p:message(s)>` are unthoughtful and untested.

[You should use jQuery. It solves everything.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif)

Based on the [`fileupload.js`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5_3/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/fileupload/fileupload.js#L2087) source code, your best bet is to listen on the fictional `show` event of the message container and then move the messages container to end of the form.

First extend `$.show()` to actually trigger the `show` event.

```
(function($) {
    var originalShowFunction = $.fn.show;
    $.fn.show = function() {
        this.trigger("show");
        return originalShowFunction.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Then simply create a listener on `show` event which basically runs when file upload messages appear and then parse every single message and use the `renderMessage()` function of the `<p:growl>` JS API. The below example assumes that you've a `<p:growl widgetVar="growl">` somewhere in the same page.

```
$(document).on("show", ".ui-fileupload-content>.ui-messages", function() {
    $(this).children().hide().find("li").each(function(index, message) {
        var $message = $(message);
        PF("growl").renderMessage({
            summary: $(".ui-messages-error-summary", $message).text(),
            detail: $(".ui-messages-error-detail", $message).text()
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Well add an message tag in your page something like:

```
<p:messages id="test" autoUpdate="true" />
```

And in fileupload update="@this,test" and your message will be displayed  in p:messages. You can change  easly in growl works the same.

Look in the primefaces showcase for more examples

Comment: Hello Tankhenk.., Not Working .

Comment: Well i dont think that is possible.

Answer (score -2):

Looked up an example in Primefaces showcase and found this. The actual page:

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"  
              mode="advanced"   
              update="messages"
              allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/"/>  

<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
```

And the file uploader controller class:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {  
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");  
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
}
```

Maybe something to keep in mind on how to display messages in Primefaces

Comment: Hello ClydeFrog.., Have tried the example from your comment?
Since you are filtering at p:fileUpload using allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/", handleFileUpload() will not be called when you upload a file other than PDF. So no message in GROWL.